# How to find stacktrace for all threads in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I need to find all stacktrace when app is running in iOS. I have used Thread.callStackSymbols, however its giving only stack symbol for that particular thread not for other thread.

Comment: Why do you need that? What do you hope to learn from it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually what you're trying to do is a very complex task.
You have to implement your own stack-walking logic to fetch a stack trace from the other threads, cause Thread.callStackSymbols will only return the stack-trace for the current thread.

I'll suggest you look at [`PLCrashReporter`](https://github.com/microsoft/plcrashreporter) source code, especially the `plframe_cursor` part (which used to be [`FrameWalker`](https://github.com/microsoft/plcrashreporter/blob/f5a0a182807df8789f912284940fbf1221926d7d/Source/PLCrashFrameWalker.h)).

In short, the steps are:

1. Fetch the thread list via `task_threads()` function: https://github.com/microsoft/plcrashreporter/blob/fd2fd7957f740f3f2589680b73da7008ea068b3c/Source/PLCrashLogWriter.m#L1243
2. Suspend threads other than the current one with `suspend_thread()`, so that the stack state does not change in these threads while the frames are being evaluated: https://github.com/microsoft/plcrashreporter/blob/fd2fd7957f740f3f2589680b73da7008ea068b3c/Source/PLCrashLogWriter.m#L1251
3. Fetch the threads states via `thread_get_state()` function:
   https://github.com/microsoft/plcrashreporter/blob/f5a0a182807df8789f912284940fbf1221926d7d/Source/PLCrashAsyncThread.c#L176
4. Walk the target's stack using the `plframe_cursor` and related methods:
   https://github.com/microsoft/plcrashreporter/blob/fd2fd7957f740f3f2589680b73da7008ea068b3c/Source/PLCrashLogWriter.m#L977